# I need advice about how to link OnlyOffice Document Server with NextCloud

Tags: request, timeout, nextcloud, onlyoffice

I'm a new Docker user and I have just installed NextCloud on my Ubuntu PC (but not using docker). I used Docker to install onlyoffice document server on https://localhost & nextcloud is on localhost /nextcloud/. I have followed instructions to the best of my understanding, i have enabled the Onlyoffice App in NextCloud and filled out the necessary details on the nextcloud admin page (see image)

[Only Office NextCloud Admin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp4HQ.png)

After I click "save" I receive the message "Error when trying to connect (bad request or timeout error)"

Any advice or link to help solve this issue would be really appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The address of the documentserver must be accessible for the user browser and from the ownCloud/Nextcloud server.
Please try using ip address or domain name in the connection settings.